# Error:Failed to find: com.android.support:support-v7:21.0.+

Tags: android

I have read various forum posts but none of them worked for me. I am inclined to believe that something has changed with the Android SDK lately, hence asking the question again in the hope of getting the latest answer.

In my SDK Manager, I have installed:

- Android SDK Tools Rev. 24
- Android SDK Platform-tools Rev. 21
- Android SDK Build-tools Rev. 21.1.1
- Everything under Android 5.0 (API 21)

I my SDK installation directory, I can see the file: sdk\sources\android-21\android\support\v7\widget\RecyclerView.java

My AndroidStudio project's SDK location is the same as the above SDK.

I want to use the class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.

However, I cannot build my application. I have just created a new application in AndroidStudio

I tried adding the dependency: compile 'com.android.support:support-v7:21.0.+' to my build.gradle file, and I get the following error:

```
Error:Failed to find: com.android.support:support-v7:21.0.+
```

What is going wrong here?

I have already tried clearing the whole folder at C:\users\.android, and re-starting SDK Manager.

Aside from this problem, I don't see Android L Dev Preview in the list of packages in SDK Manager, but see Android 5.0 instead. I suppose that is okay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you forget to install the **Android Support Repository**?

It is mentioned as a side note in the setup guide for the [support library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#download)

Regarding your question on the Android L Dev Preview: You don't see it because the [final version](http://android-developers.blogspot.ch/2014/10/android-50-lollipop-sdk-and-nexus.html) is already available (which you have installed).

Comment: Thanks! That was the missing piece. It worked after installing Support Repository. Apart from that I had to include com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:+ in my build.gradle

Comment: @Bonton255 Happy to help - I extended my answer to cover your question about the preview of Android L.